# Error when running java bat file for rsps

Tags: java

This is the code:

```
"@echo off
@title RSE - 742
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\java.exe" org.rse.Server 
pause"
```

when I run it. It tells me `could not find or load main class org.rse.server`

I really need help with this

Answer (score 0):

This should be the contents of batch file. (**NO QUOTES AT THE BEGINNING AND AT THE END**)

```
@echo off
@title RSE - 742
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\java.exe" org.rse.Server 
pause
```

This is how you directory structure should look.

```
|-- script.bat
`-- org
    `-- rse
        `-- Server.class
```

The error `could not find or load main class org.rse.Server` is because the directory structure is incorrect.

Please ensure that the `class Server` is `public` and contains a method `public static void main(String[] args) {}`